# Adding panel content to pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: c#

I am new to iTextSharp for generating pdf's and got this problem when I was trying to add panel which contains background image to PDF using iTextSharp. So, I am trying to figure out, how it can be achieved. Looking for your suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I was trying to add panel"? What have you tried? Did you look at the [BackgroundImage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/BackgroundImage) example? Do you need automated backgrounds as shown in the [PageBackgrounds](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/PageBackgrounds) example? Your question is very unclear. I doubt if anyone can answer it, because I fear that nobody understands your requirement (at least: I don't).

Comment: Along with what Bruno said, you also need to ignore every widget or component that's common to programming inside of Visual Studio, both for desktop and for web, when dealing with PDFs. For instance, a `Panel` is generally a container for things that can be stretched and docked but there isn't really any equivalent thing in a PDF. Also, the various data-bound things like `GridViews` don't exist.